# Point webpack production to different API url

Tags: angular, webpack

I am using `webpack` in my `angular 4` project. It is pointing to same url for `api`. Now, for production, I have different API url so where should I exact put new url ? I am using `jhipster` project.
**Source:** https://jhipster.github.io/using-angular/
**webpack.prod.js :**

```
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const Visualizer = require('webpack-visualizer-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const ENV = 'prod';

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig({ env: ENV }), {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('./build/www'),
        filename: '[hash].[name].bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: '[hash].[id].chunk.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('[hash].styles.css'),
        new Visualizer({
            // Webpack statistics in target folder
            filename: '../stats.html'
        })
    ]
});
```

Comment: Not sure if this will do it for you, but have you tried adding an output property to your module.exports? `output: { publicPath: '/' },`

Comment: by `Different API URL` what you mean? you `dev env` will call consume `localhost:1000` your `prod env`  must use `localhost:4000` ? correct?

Comment: @Aravind, I want to connect `prod env` to external url, not `localhost`.

Comment: @Aravind, Can you help me to go ahead ?

Comment: What is the issue currently you are facing

Comment: @Aravind `devServer` is there in `webpack.dev` and it is working fine. Now, I want to publish this project in production so what changes shall i do in `webpack.prod` file ? I want to point different api in production.

Comment: @Aravind check skype.

Comment: @JeetenParmar so the devserver config helped?

Comment: @alphapilgrim, it is not working for production.

Comment: @Aravind My api server is different for production so how do i setup proxy or target ? `devServer` is there in development and so it is working fine but I have issue only with production.

Comment: @Aravind As I can see webpack, there is `proxy` in `webpack.dev` and so it is working fine with 3rd party api. How do I setup `proxy` in `webpack.prod` ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to treat your **environment-dependent variables** as actual **environment variables**, as stated by the [3rd rule](https://12factor.net/config) of the twelve-factor app approach.

You won't overload your code with ever-changing environment stuff, and you'll be able to easily update them from outside the application, even directly from your deploy system.

In a node environment, I personally prefer storing those variables into a dedicated `.env` file placed in the root of my project.

```
VAR_1=foo
VAR_2=bar
```

You might have a different `.xxx.env` file for each environment or switch the file programmatically before the build.

In order to make the declared env vars available to your code, I suggest to use [webpack-dotenv-plugin](https://github.com/nwinch/webpack-dotenv-plugin).

You'll be able to get your environment variables from your application like standard node's user environment vars:

```
const var1 = process.env.VAR_1;   // foo
const var2 = process.env.VAR_2;   // bar
```

Comment: My api server is different for production so how do i setup proxy or target ? `devServer` is there in development and so it is working fine but I have issue only with production.

Comment: So you want to know how to use `webpack dev server` in production? Please note it is possible by and large, but it is a discouraged practice.

Comment: As I can see webpack, there is `proxy` in `webpack.dev` and so it is working fine with 3rd party api. How do I setup `proxy` in `webpack.prod` ?

Answer (score 0):

[DOCS](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html) or [V2](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/). Also, might want to consider adding a public path to your output object(something to explore).
You simply edit your host file to contain the domain you want, and then add the following code to your webpack.config:

```js
devServer: {
  host: "localhost.specialurl.com",
  port: 1234,
  https: true
},



//webpack.production.config.js
var path = require('path');
var mainPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'app', 'main.js');
var buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'build');

entry: mainPath,
  output: {

    // Everything related to Webpack should go through a build path,
    // localhost:3000/build. That makes proxying easier to handle
    path: buildPath,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
```

Comment: I am unable to add `devServer` in `webpack.config`. I mean I can't see option `devServer`.

Comment: Can you help me to go ahead ?

Comment: Just copy and paste this into your webpack config. Change the URL into the one you need. Run the dev server.

Comment: My api server is different for production so how do i setup proxy or target ? `devServer` is there in development and so it is working fine but I have issue only with production.

Comment: @JeetenParmar are you talking about output.path?

Comment: also what version of webpack are you using, @JeetenParmar?

Comment: As I can see webpack, there is `proxy` in `webpack.dev` and so it is working fine with 3rd party api. How do I setup `proxy` in `webpack.prod` ?